# Изменить путь у изображений которые не загрузились. JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Подскажите пожалуйста, где ошибка в скрипте?

```
function imgResize(){
    $(".search-img img").each(function() {
      var image = this;
      image.onerror = function() {
      var src_img = this.src;
         if(src_img.indexOf("/1/") !== -1){
              var nesrc = src_img.replace("/1/", "/2/");
              this.src = nesrc;
         } else if(src_img.indexOf("/2/") !== -1){
              var nesrc = src_img.replace("/2/", "/1/");
              this.src = nesrc;
         }
      }
    })
}
```

Логика такая - Ищем изображения с ошибкой 404, и меняем у них путь с /1/ на /2/ и наоборот. nesrc - корректно исправляет, но не срабатывает this.src = nesrc почему то

Comment: Все ответы, которые Вам дали, делают примерно одно и то же. Если они у Вас не работают, значит в Вашем коде есть что-то не включенное в вопрос, о чем мы не можем догадаться.

Answer (score 1):

> но не срабатывает this.src = nesrc почему то

Потому что не надо смешивать атрибут `src` и свойство `src`.

```
image.onerror = function() {
  var src = this.src;
  ...
  this.src = nesrc;
}
```

Comment: Поправил, поменял название переменной, по прежнему не меняет, может это из-за того что скрипт вызывает когда картинки еще не подгруились?

Comment: @ilyaaa521 При чем здесь название переменной?

Comment: Я вас не совсем понимаю, var src = this.src разве отличается от const src_img = $(image).attr("src") ?

Comment: @ilyaaa521 Да, отличается. Почему бы Вам самому в этом не убедиться, сделав `console.log(image.src, $(image).attr("src"));`?

Comment: я поправил код, сделал так как вы сказали, но результат тот же

Comment: @ilyaaa521 Ну выведите уже в консоль эти строки в конце `onerror`: `console.log("In onerror", src_img, nesrc, this.src);`

Comment: In onerror https://t.ru/images/detailed/1/NP__6__hxif-ci_cfk0-rw.png https://t.ru/images/detailed/2/NP__6__hxif-ci_cfk0-rw.png https://t.ru/images/detailed/2/NP__6__hxif-ci_cfk0-rw.png
Получается что src_img это не коретная ссылка, остальные корректные

Answer (score 1):

В опубликованной части вашего скрипта явных ошибок я не вижу. Возможно, ошибка кроется в какой-то другой части скрипта. Если картинка не хочет загружаться по смене `src` после ошибки загрузки, то стоит попробовать заменить тег `<img>` другой картинкой, которая еще не загружалась. Как-то так:

```
  var image = this;
  image.onerror = function() {
     var newImg = new Image();
     newImg.src = this.src.replace("/1/", "/2/");
     this.replaceWith(newImg);
  }
```

Comment: "Попробуйте так." - Зачем? Чем это принципиально отличается от уже предложенного решения?

Comment: @Igor ну код создаёт новую картинку, получает новый путь до файла картинки, замещает текущую картинку новой. Не знаю. Вроде бы, должно работать и так и так. Но принципы немного разные.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin каюсь, исправил ответ